# Can company see what I'm browsing when using personal wifi and portable browser with a company laptop

Tags: company

I'm wondering if the following information can be monitored:

- Website accessed
- Logins/Passwords
- Downloads on a non-encrypted and non-backed-up place of the company computer

When using a company computer connected solely to a mobile wifi (over 4g) access point and using a portable browser which erases history before the computer is reconnected on company network

Comment: It can be monitored if it's targeted to be monitored by someone who knows what to do.

Comment: Always assume so

Comment: Already an answer to this, but I want to add. Some countries and states require the employer to let you know if you're being monitored. Just Google it for your area and see if your company is required to inform you, and check your company handbook etc...

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @fenryr628. This depends on the company and the device(s) you're using which is always company-specific and those questions are off-topic here. If you're after a more general answer a site like [security.se] *might* be able to explain some of the concepts or how you can find out.

Comment: Literally anything you do on the internet can be monitored. All you can do is take precautions to make it more difficult, a major one being not using a device provided by the people you don't want monitoring you.

Answer (score 16):

If the company provided you with the computer then they could have installed any kind of software to monitor whatever they want.

If you are worried about security or privacy then do not use the company computer for anything other than company work.